# Suppose a linear system of 4 equations in 4 unknowns has two distinct solutions. Prove that the system must have an infinite number of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a linear system of 4 equations in 4 unknowns has two distinct solutions. Prove that the system must have an infinite number of solutions.

i've always been taught that if it has 2 solutions.. it has infinite. I never really saw how this was proved before. how am i supposed to prove this?

Comment: The claim is not true if the ground field has characteristic $\n 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the system as a linear equation with matrices. You are solving the equation $$Ax=b$$ for some matrix $A$ and some vector $b$. You know that $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2=b$, meaning that $$A(x_1-x_2) = Ax_1-Ax_2=b-b=0$$
so that means $$A(x_1 + \lambda(x_1-x_2)) = Ax_1 + \lambda A(x_1-x_2) = b + 0 = b$$
for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

Since you know that $x_1-x_2\neq 0$, you know that for each $\lambda\notin \{0,-1\}$, the vector $x_1 + \lambda(x_1-x_2)$ is a new solution different from $x_1$ and $x_2$ (and different for any other solution for any other $\lambda$).

Comment: you lost me at A(x1+λ(x1−x2))=Ax1+λA(x1−x2)=b+0=b

what does λ mean?

Comment: $\lambda$ is, as I wrote, any real number. Reading the whole argument may, occasionally, help you in understanding it.